# Perl - detect not installed modoules and return inform message

Tags: perl, module, detect

I use `use Term::Size::Any qw( chars pixels );` in my script. But if this module is not installed, perl throws an error: `Can't locate Term/Size/Any.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::Size::Any module)`.
What is the way to catch this error and inform user that he/she has not this module installed and must install it before run a script? 
I tried to check installed modules before run but it does not work. I also tried to use `Try::Tiny;` but it didn't help also.

Comment: The error message already informs the user that they may need to install the module...

Comment: Yes. But it is a form of an error. I want to catch it or something and return only a message, for example `You do not have this module`

Comment: Ok, it solved a problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444773/custom-missing-module-message

Comment: If you do this, you'll want to make your error message much more informative, since people won't be able to find your custom error message in the documentation or on google. "You do not have this module" isn't necessarily true; it could be installed, but just somewhere that perl can't find it. Personally, I would use the default message to make it easier for people to research when something goes wrong.